# supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow not working for IOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

My app is only visible in Portrait. No problem with the main ViewController. but MPMoviePlayerController is for all the  Orientation.

Here is my code that works perfectly for the IOS6. but now its not working for the IOS7

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    if ([[self.window.subviews.lastObject class].description isEqualToString:@"MPMovieView"] || [[self.window.subviews.lastObject class].description isEqualToString:@"MPSwipableView"]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    }
    else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Please need a help..

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the settings in General tag of your target? To be only the Portrait selected (under the Deployment info)

Comment: Try to look at object "self.window.subviews.lastObject" - are you sure it's exactly you are expecting for?